# trying to use ring.middleware.json-params with compojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen, compojure, ring

I am new to Clojure, leiningen, and java tool chains (but not to lisp, functional programming, software in general).  I'm trying to bootstrap some RESTful web services in Compojure.

I had no trouble getting started with compojure, following the instructions at

```
https://github.com/weavejester/compojure/wiki/Getting-Started
```

I am now trying to *incrementally* add in functionality from the now-outdated web site

```
http://mmcgrana.github.com/2010/08/clojure-rest-api.html
```

Starting with the working `leiningen` project from the first link above (it works via `lein ring start`, I add ONE line to project.clj

```
(defproject hello-world "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [ring-json-params "0.1.3"]  ;;; <---===/// Here's the line I added
                 [compojure "1.1.5"]]
  :plugins [[lein-ring "0.8.2"]]
  :ring {:handler hello-world.handler/app}
  :profiles
  {:dev {:dependencies [[ring-mock "0.1.3"]]}})
```

Then I rerun `lein deps` and a bunch of stuff downloads.  All good, the project still works.  Now I add one line to `handler.clj`:

```
(ns hello-world.handler
  (:use     compojure.core)
  (:use     ring.middleware.json-params)  ;;; <---===/// Here's the line I added
  (:require [compojure.handler :as handler]
            [compojure.route :as route]))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] "Hello World")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))
```

And now I get

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate ring/middleware/json_params__init.class or ring/middleware/json_params.clj on classpath: 
 at clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:432)
    clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:400)
    clojure.core$load$fn__4890.invoke (core.clj:5415)
    clojure.core$load.doInvoke (core.clj:5414)
```

Since I am a total noob to the toolchain, I don't know how to set or inspect the classpath or to find out where `json_params` was deposited by leiningen, or even how to look inside the class files to find out what the name should have been.

In addition to a specific solution to this problem, I would appreciate pointers to newbie stuff so maybe I can solve straightforward problems like this on my own in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get that error when you start the server? Nothing is wrong on my enviroment.
[image]

Here's what i have done:

```
lein new compojure hello
```

Then change project.clj as you do and run:

```
lein deps
```

At last add:

```
(:use ring.middleware.json-params)
```

to handle.clj

Start server, no error occurs.

I suggest you building a new project and try again.

Comment: I got the error when I compiled the project in emacs nrepl .... looks like the problem is there, in the emacs part of the toolchain -- the one part i didn't report on.  `lein ring server` is working.

Comment: -- Yup, restarting emacs and redoing `nrepl-jack-in` solved the problem.  Looks like changing the project.clj you have to restart `nrepl` from the project.clj directory.  Makes sense.  Thanks for the clue!

Comment: It seems you don't have to restart everything when changing project.clj. Just nrepl-eval-buffer that file and it would be known to nrepl server.